# Skipping and identifying password protected excel files while running a loop

Tags: python, pandas

we are working on a script that would take a lot of files and combine them in to one dataframe. Unfortunately we encounter the problem where the loop stops when there is a password protected file. What I am trying to figure out is how to skip the password protected excel file and also have the script tell me which of them is password protected.

```
df_list = []
allfiles = glob.glob(path)

for xlsx in allfiles:
  temp_df = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
  df_list.append(temp_df)
```

Right not it will spit out an error stating "BadZipFile" if there is an excel document that is password protected. Since there are hundreds of files we have to open them 1 by 1 to identify which ones have a password

Comment: Why don't you just use normal `try/except` error handling for this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to handle Exception, think about try/except: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Here is a possible solution:

```
df_list = []
allfiles = glob.glob(path)
protected_files=[]

for xlsx in allfiles:
    try:
        temp_df = pd.read_excel(xlsx)
    except BadZipfile:
        protected_files.append(xlsx)
    else:
        df_list.append(temp_df)
```

The `protected_files` list will contain the files that are protected